# Javascript : How can I add X elements to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create an array including the first 100 prime numbers, here is my code:

```
var premier= [];
var nombre= premier.length;

function isPrime(n)
{
    if(n < 2)
    {
        return false;
    }

    for(i=2; i<Math.sqrt(n); i++)
    {
        if(n%i===0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true
};

while(nombre<100)
{
    var j=2
    if(isPrime(j)==true)
    {
        premier.push(j);
    }
    j=j+1
}
```

I am a beginner in Javascript, but I have tested the `isPrime` function and it works fine even forlarge numbers.

but when I run the program I have:

FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory

I think this part is wrong:

```
while(nombre<100)
{
    var j=2
    if(isPrime(j)=true)
    {
        premier.push(j);
    }
    j=j+1
}
console.log(premier)
```

But I can't tell why

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: are you updating the value of `nombre` after pushing data into the array ?

Comment: `isPrime(j)=true` won't even run. It is invalid as a function call cannot appear on the left-hand-side of an assignment. I assume that `==` was desired, but *it isn't useful to post fundamentally broken non-parsing code*; much less when the appropriate error message(s) are not included.

Answer (score 3):

You are repeatedly setting `j=2` every time the loop runs, and you never change `nombre` so the loop will never end. Note that JavaScript sets literal vaues by value, not by reference, so `nombre = premier.length` won't magically update.

Additionally, statements of the form `if( x = true)` will *set* `x` to true, and then pass the condition automatically. In this case, since `x` is a function call, it is invalid syntax.

Did you mean this?

```
var j = 2;
while(premier.length < 100) {
    if( isPrime(j)) premier.push(j);
    j++;
}
```